# .htaccess: Rewriting Query Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change the URL from:

`/chat/create?ref=9dsda` to `/chat/create/refer/9dsda`

However, everytime I go to the lather, I get the error:

`Not Found: The requested URL /chat/create/ref/9dsda was not found on this server.`

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/create/refer/([^/]+) /create?ref=$1
```

I've tried several things such as adding `RewriteBase /chat/` without success.

Comment: Inside `.htaccess` style files there is no leading slash (`/`) in the request path, since it is _relative_ here. That is one of the differences to using the real host configuration instead of `.htaccess` style files.

Comment: @arkascha Sadly this did not fix the issue. Thank you though!

Comment: Is the usage of such `.htaccess` style files enabled _at all_? You can test that by placing a definite syntax error in the file. Do you get an error 500 then?

Comment: The htaccess file is enabled. I know this because I got rid of the .php extensions using it.

Comment: Then probably the file is at the wrong location or the paths are wrong. Do you have access to the real http servers host configuration? In that case you should prefer that over `.htaccess` files anyway. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow the server down. If you do not have access, then you have to try check the location of that file considering the path notation you use.

Answer (score 0):

If your htaccess is in the root ,try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^chat/create/refer/([^/]+)/?$ /chat/create?ref=$1 [L]
```

If it is inside the /chat dir ,try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^create/refer/([^/]+)/?$ /chat/create?ref=$1 [L]
```

htaccess is a per-directory context so you don't need to match against the folder that the htaccess is in.

Comment: The htaccess file is indeed in the root. I tried out your top code without success. The htaccess file is enabled though. I know this because I got rid of the `.php` extensions using it.

Comment: @Shawn31313 then your other rules might be conflicting with this one. Try reorderng your rules. This should be placed as a  very first rule in your htaccess.